# How do I loop over rows and columns of a pandas dataframe in jinja2?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, jinja2

I am just starting out with jinja2 and trying to generate lines of text from a dataframe. My template `weather.txt` looks like this:

```
{% for key, value in x.iterrows %}
    The day {{ df["date"] }} was {{ df["weather"] }}.
{% endfor %}
```

The dataframe `weather` looks something like this:

```
      date        weather
0  2017-03-31      warm
1  2017-04-21      cold
2  2017-07-01      rainy
```

Now I can't really figure out how to generate the desired output from this. When I use this code:

```
template = env.get_template("weather.txt")

output = template.render(x = weather)
print(output)
```

I get `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the warning states, `iterrows` is a method, so you need to use parentheses:

```
{% for _, row in weather.iterrows() %}
    The day {{ row["date"] }} was {{ row["weather"] }}.
{% endfor %}
```

This should work assuming your dataframe is indeed called `weather`